# AngularJS: why custom filter is trigger when textbox text change occur

Tags: angularjs

i am new in angular. so every day i read many article on angular. i was reading a article on custom filter. i see the code and test it....found working but one area not clear that why my custom filter is trigger when user change value in text box?

but there is no relation between custom filter and text box. please see the code and tell me the reason what is relation between textbox and customer filter for which when textbox value change then custom filter `SearchList` is firing. see the code please and guide me to understand the area where i have the confusion.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
 <label>Field: 
   <select ng-model="selectedFieldName">
      <option value="">--Select Account--</option>
          <option ng-repeat="(fieldname,fieldvalue) in customer[0]" ng-value="fieldname | uppercase">{{fieldname | uppercase}}</option>
   </select>  
</label>

<label>data: <input ng-model="searchText"></label>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <tr>
          <td>ID</td>
          <td>First Name</td>
          <td>Last Name</td>
          <td>Salary</td>
          <td>Date of Birth</td>
          <td>City</td>
          <td>Phone</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in customer | filter:SearchList ">
        <!-- orderBy:'$index':false -->
            <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.firstname }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.lastname }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.salary }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.dob }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.city }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.phone }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>


var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {

    $scope.selectedFieldName='';
    $scope.searchText='';

        $scope.SearchList = function(row) {

    if ($scope.selectedFieldName && $scope.searchText) {
      var propVal = row[$scope.selectedFieldName.toLowerCase()]+ '';
      if (propVal) {
        return propVal.toUpperCase().indexOf($scope.searchText.toUpperCase()) > -1;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;    
  };

    $scope.customer = [
      {
          'id': 1,
          'firstname': 'Tridip',
          'lastname': 'Bhattacharjee',
          'salary' : 15000,
          'dob': '05/09/2013',
          'city': 'kolkata',
          'phone': '033 2589 7415'
      },
      {
          'id': 2,
          'firstname': 'Arijit',
          'lastname': 'Banerjee',
          'salary' : 25000,
          'dob': '01/09/2010',
          'city': 'Bihar',
          'phone': '033 2589 9999'
      },
      {
          'id': 3,
          'firstname': 'Dibyendu',
          'lastname': 'Saha',
          'salary' : 20000,
          'dob': '06/09/2011',
          'city': 'Rachi',
          'phone': '033 2589 3333'
      },
      {
          'id': 4,
          'firstname': 'Bisu',
          'lastname': 'Das',
          'salary' : 5000,
          'dob': '05/01/2009',
          'city': 'Silchar',
          'phone': '033 2589 2222'
      },
      {
          'id': 5,
          'firstname': 'Soumyajit',
          'lastname': 'Kar',
          'salary' : 12000,
          'dob': '09/08/2011',
          'city': 'kanpur',
          'phone': '033 3333 1894'
      }
    ];
})
```

see js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zjxa5g8o/

Comment: Please read about scope in angular js https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

Comment: when i am changing dropdown data only and textbox remain empty then i saw custom filter is firing 5 times because i have 5 data in array but when i am putting value in textbox then custom filter is firing 10 times.....why? share the reason.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that Angular runs every single filter twice per $digest cycle once something has changed. You can read more about this in [this](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/speeding-up-angular-js-with-simple-optimizations/135) article written by Todd Motto.

Comment: Just to add to the answer, AngularJS official site has a good example/explanation on [filtering the repeaters](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_03).

Comment: if u r trying to say that when textbox data is changing then digest cycle is getting change and that is why custom filter is triggering....if so then when we change value from dropdown then digest cycle should change but in that case custom filter is not trigger.........why?

Comment: when i am changing dropdown data only and textbox remain empty then i saw custom filter is firing 5 times because i have 5 data in array but when i am putting value in textbox then custom filter is firing 10 times.....why? share the reason.